# Heroku Postgres connection from another ec2 instance

Tags: heroku

How can i connect to heroku postgres from another webapplication running on different cloud service.

I have a heroku postgres. I have another webapplication running on EC2. When my webapp on ec2 is trying to connect to heroku app, it fails.

I tried telnet from ec2 instance to heroku postgres on port 5432, it fails.

Can anyone please provide a pointer?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `heroku pg:credentials` command to get the credentials for your database. For example:

```
$ heroku pg:credentials DATABASE_URL 
Connection info string:
   "dbname=abcdefghijklmn host=ec2-1-2-3-4.compute-1.amazonaws.com port=5432 user=abcdefghijklmn password=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz sslmode=require"
Connection URL:
    postgres://abcdefghijklmn:abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz@ec2-1-2-3-4.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/abcdefghijklmn
```

Then, you can use Connection URL or decomposed credentials in your other application. Pay attention to `sslmode=require`. Connections to Heroku Postgres require you to use SSL, which is an "advanced" option in some of the PostgreSQL clients (e.g. Navicat). For example:

```
$ psql postgres://abcdefghijklmn:abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz@ec2-1-2-3-4.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/abcdefghijklmn
```

More information here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#external-connections-ingress